# Animation Not Working in Mozilla

Tags: html, css

Hi This may be a repeat question, I am sorry if it is so, but I get anything substantial on my search.

I have written animation, that works well in chrome, but somehow it doesn't work in Mozilla. Any help from anyone is highly appreciated

```
.truck-size{
 background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck0.png")no-repeat center center;
 height: 100px;

  -webkit-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
  animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
  -moz-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
  -o-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;

}



@-webkit-keyframes truck-change {
    0% {background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck0.png")no-repeat center center;height: 100px;}
    100% {background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck20.png")no-repeat center center;height: 100px;}
}

@keyframes truck-change {
    0% {background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck0.png")no-repeat center center;height: 100px;}
    100% {background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck20.png")no-repeat center center;height: 100px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes truck-change {
    0% {background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck0.png")no-repeat center center;height: 100px;}
    100% {background: url("../img/truck-animation/truck20.png")no-repeat center center;height: 100px;}
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a demo in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yksg35xc/

but this fiddle is working in both chrome and firefox, but i am still unable to get it to work on my local firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation doesn't work in case of background images. Firefox doesn't support interpolating between background-images.

That explains why your code works across all browsers in case of `background-color` and why it doesn't in case of `background-image`

Refer this entry: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1036761
and http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2699753

CSS:

```
.truck-size {
    background-color:black;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
    animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
    -moz-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
    -o-animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite truck-change;
}
@-webkit-keyframes truck-change {
    0% {
        background:red;
        height: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        background:yellow;
        height: 100px;
    }
}
@keyframes truck-change {
    0% {
        background-color:red;
        height: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        background:yellow;
        height: 100px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes truck-change {
    0% {
        background-color:red;
        height: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        background:yellow;
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yksg35xc/

Comment: @gunj_desai It's okay :)